# Как использовать df.rolling(..., win_type='exponential').mean()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, машинное-обучение, статистика

Я хочу рассчитать взвешенное скользящее среднее при помощи `df.rolling().mean()`. Веса для значений в окне можно задать при помощи параметра `win_type`. Некоторые значения параметра (подробнее [тут](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)), также требуют ввода дополнительного аргумента.

```
# здесь дополнительный аргумент std в методе .mean()
df.rolling(window=21, min_periods=10, win_type='gaussian').mean(std=1) 
# работает
```

Но когда доходит дело до `win_type='exponential'`

```
`df.rolling(window=21, min_periods=10, win_type='exponential').mean(tau=10)
# ValueError: The 'exponential' window needs one or more parameters -- pass a tuple.
```

Подскажите, как правильно использовать экспоненциально взвешенное скользящее среднее  `win_type='exponential`?

#### UPD: Добавлены df

Дан сет `a`

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[1, 20, 1], [2, 22, 1], [3, 23, 0], [1, 19, 1], [2, 24, 0],
                 [2, 21, 1], [1, 17, 1], [2, 29, 0], [2, 27, 0]],
                 columns=['type', 'size', 'target'])
```

Все преобразования, кроме `win_type='exponential'` работают

```
a = a.assign(rolling_col=a.groupby(['type'])['size'].transform(
lambda x: x.rolling(2, min_periods=1, win_type='gaussian').mean(std=0.1)))
```

даст на выходе

```
  type size target rolling_col
    1   20  1   20.0 # В данному примере rolling_col рассчитан при помощи win_type='gaussian'
    2   22  1   22.0 # a должен быть рассчитан при win_type='exponential'
    3   23  0   23.0
    1   19  1   19.5
    2   24  0   23.0
    2   21  1   22.5
    1   17  1   18.0
    2   29  0   25.0
    2   27  0   28.0
```

Не работает с `win_type='exponential'` , выдаёт:

```
 # ValueError: The 'exponential' window needs one or more parameters -- pass a tuple.
```

Comment: можете привести в вопросе небольшой пример входных и выходных данных?

Comment: Добавил. Наверное, можно реализовать при помощи pandas.DataFrame.ewm(), но хотелось бы понять как в данном случае работает pd.rolling()

Comment: Вы добавили тот фрейм, который хотите получить? Тогда в чем суть вопроса? Или я вас неправильно понял?

Comment: Добавил условный фрейм, который хочу получить: к исходному df, добавляется скользящее среднее, рассчитанное при помощи pd.rolling по указанным колонкам. Меня интересует параметр win_type, который отвечает за присваиваемые веса для значений в окне и я пробую различные его значения, чтобы потом проверить на CV.  Вопрос в том, что один из способов расчета скользящего среднего, а именно с значением win_type='exponential', по какой-то причине не работает и выдает указанную ошибку - почему? В гугле ответа не нашел, на stackoverflow.com есть аналогичный вопрос, но он без ответа уже несколько недель.

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57518576/how-to-use-df-rollingwindow-min-periods-win-type-exponential-sum
Если я понял, можно использовать такой подход: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705908/calculating-the-rolling-exponential-weighted-moving-average-for-each-share-price
Но вопрос тот же: что я не так ввожу в коде, что функция pd.rolling() не работает с win_type='exponential'?

Comment: @MaxU, скажите, пожалуйста, получилось объяснить суть вопроса?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного поэксперементировав и внимательно перечитав сообщение об ошибке, пришел к такому варианту:

```
In [14]: a.assign(rolling_col=
    ...:   a.groupby(['type'])[['size']].transform(
    ...:     lambda x: x.rolling(window=(2,10), min_periods=1, win_type='exponential').mean(std=0.1)))
Out[14]:
   type  size  target  rolling_col
0     1    20       1    20.000000
1     2    22       1    22.000000
2     3    23       0    23.000000
3     1    19       1    19.166667
4     2    24       0    23.666667
5     2    21       1    21.500000
6     1    17       1    17.333333
7     2    29       0    27.666667
8     2    27       0    27.333333
```

**NOTE:** обратите внимание на параметр `window=(2,10)`, где вторым элементом кортежа является значение `tau`.

---

PS [из официальной документации](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

> ```
> win_types
> ```
>
> - exponential (needs `tau`), center is set to None.

Comment: Спасибо большое, не догадался. Также разместил ваш ответ с ссылкой на этот на английском форуме https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57518576/how-to-use-df-rollingwindow-min-periods-win-type-exponential-sum/57679124#57679124